# How to add multiple columns to data frame using loops

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 2 columns viz "dateperiod" and "temp" like so :-

```
dateperiod,temp
01/01/2019,20.995
02/01/2019,19.89
03/01/2019,17.68
04/01/2019,16.575
05/01/2019,12.155
06/01/2019,13.26
07/01/2019,16.575
08/01/2019,13.26
09/01/2019,19.89
```

For a specified number of times (say n = 3), I am looking to be able to create 6 (n * 2) number of columns like so :-

```
dateperiod,temp,temp_plus1,temp_plus2,temp_plus3,temp_minus1,temp_minus2,temp_minus3
01/01/2019,20.995,21.995,22.995,23.995,19.995,18.995,17.995
02/01/2019,19.89,20.89,21.89,22.89,18.89,17.89,16.89
03/01/2019,17.68,18.68,19.68,20.68,16.68,15.68,14.68
04/01/2019,16.575,17.575,18.575,19.575,15.575,14.575,13.575
05/01/2019,12.155,13.155,14.155,15.155,11.155,10.155,9.155
06/01/2019,13.26,14.26,15.26,16.26,12.26,11.26,10.26
07/01/2019,16.575,17.575,18.575,19.575,15.575,14.575,13.575
08/01/2019,13.26,14.26,15.26,16.26,12.26,11.26,10.26
09/01/2019,19.89,20.89,21.89,22.89,18.89,17.89,16.89
```

The idea being that the values in the 3 "plus" value columns are the original values incremented by 'n' and those in the 3 "minus" value columns are the original values decremented by 'n' as shown in the lower table.

I couldn't work out a way to loop (or use any of the apply functions), so I have only manually added these columns. But I would like to automate it for larger number of added columns where the value of 'n' is high.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards

Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `purrr` we can use `map_dfc` to create new columns

```
library(purrr) 
cbind(df, map_dfc(1:3, ~ list(df$temp + .x, df$temp - .x)))


#  dateperiod   temp     V1     V2     V3     V4     V5     V6
#1 01/01/2019 20.995 21.995 19.995 22.995 18.995 23.995 17.995
#2 02/01/2019 19.890 20.890 18.890 21.890 17.890 22.890 16.890
#3 03/01/2019 17.680 18.680 16.680 19.680 15.680 20.680 14.680
#4 04/01/2019 16.575 17.575 15.575 18.575 14.575 19.575 13.575
#5 05/01/2019 12.155 13.155 11.155 14.155 10.155 15.155  9.155
#6 06/01/2019 13.260 14.260 12.260 15.260 11.260 16.260 10.260
#7 07/01/2019 16.575 17.575 15.575 18.575 14.575 19.575 13.575
#8 08/01/2019 13.260 14.260 12.260 15.260 11.260 16.260 10.260
#9 09/01/2019 19.890 20.890 18.890 21.890 17.890 22.890 16.890
```

Comment: Ronak <- Thanks too. That one looks easier but I will try both and let you all know! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ronak <- Thanksm, that works beautifully! No worries at all.

Comment: Santiago <- That comes out a list of 3 items each with 2 columns. Is there a way outside of using map_dfc where these 6 columns can be combined in to one data frame? It also comes up with an error for 'simplify = true' as unused argument. Any suggestions as why am I getting this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal If you do `temp <- cbind(df, map_dfc(1:3, ~ list(df$temp + .x, df$temp - .x)))` and then check `dim(temp)` it shows 9 rows and 8 columns right? Also it did not give me any warning/error with that function.

Comment: Ronak <- Why do you need to use list funciton - what does the list() function do? Also, doesn't cbind work with vectors or data frames? The errors weren't for your bit. It came up when I used the "simplify" option for the lapply function advised by Santiago.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal For every value (`1:3`) we want two new columns so we bind them in `list()` function so when we use `map_dfc` each of those values are turned into separate column. For example, if you replace `list` with `c` like `cbind(df, map_dfc(1:3, ~ c(df$temp + .x, df$temp - .x)))` check how those are converted to separate rows and not columns, hence we need to use `list`.

Comment: Ronak <- I did check that and it did convert to rows. I still have a question. When I do 'x <- list(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6), c = c(7,8,9))', I get  x <-$a, [1] 1 2 3
$b, [1] 4 5 6, $c [1] 7 8 9 and not as columns as you get. Even when I do cbind(list...).

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Sorry, I didn't get you. What is `x`? How are you using it here? Instead of `1:3` you now want to do it for the list you could do `cbind(df, map_dfc(unlist(x), ~ list(df$temp + .x, df$temp - .x)))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try lapply() with cbind.data.frame():

```
df_2 <- lapply(1:3, function(x) {
a <- df$temp + x
b <- df$temp - x
return(cbind.data.frame(a, b))
}, simplify = TRUE)

cbind.data.frame(df, df_2)
```

Being df, your original data. Then you can rename and order the colmns as you want.

Hope it helps

Comment: <- Thanks. Don't understand it immediately but I will give it a go and let you know!